# Changing the icon of an exe using Resource Hacker from the command line

Tags: windows

I'm trying to change the icon of an exe I have already compiled (can't recompile).
I've read that you can do this using CLI by doing:
ResHacker.exe -addoverwrite "FILE.exe", "FILE_OUT.exe", "ICON_FILE.ico", ICONGROUP, MAINICON, 0

My problem is that I tested this exe in several VMs.

On Windows 7 & 8 I see the new icon.
On XP & Server 2003, I see the "blank" icon [Here's how it looks, it's basically white with a blue menu bar on top](http://www.pixentral.com/pics/1TeXLUQEsiVCPghK7UZKv1DWQvKC.png)

The exe is a 7zip SFX. Anyone knows what could be going on?

Thanks.

Comment: The icon file has to include icons of the right size, maybe your icons are too big for XP. Check out http://iconhandbook.co.uk/reference/chart/windows/

Comment: Thanks, that was the problem!